Tile dominoes in a 3x10 space
How many ways are there to tile 1x2 (unmarked) dominoes in a 3x10 space?
This is a harder version of Tile dominoes in a 2x10 space, since that was too easy.

https://oeis.org/A001835

@RobPratt: That looks like an answer posted in the form of a comment! (And to OP: This kind of calculation problem isn't really a "puzzle" in the sense we mean it here. You wouldn't ask "What is 29832623 times 23873827", either, even though a multiplication problem resembles a puzzle in some ways.)

@Quuxplusone you might as well get everything rid of every question in tiling and all those "how many squares can you make with lines" questions

And throw away all those "find the closest expression using digits to this constant" questions too, because they're even more computational than my question. In fact my question doesn't require much computation at all.

Lemma:

 Any 3xN grid must end with either 3 horizontal dominoes, or a vertical domino preceded by a nonnegative number of pairs of horizontal dominoes and another vertical domino. (The remaining row is filled with horizontal dominoes until the next vertical domino.)

The proof should be trivial and is omitted here.
From this, we derive the recurrence relation

 $F(N) = F(N-2) + 2(F(N-2)+F(N-4)+ \dots + F(2) + F(0)),$ where $F(N)$ is the number of ways to tile a 3xN grid and $F(0)=1.$ Note that in the second case, the configuration can be inverted, hence the multiplication by two.

Now, it is trivial to evaluate the final answer:

 $F(0) = 1, F(2) = 3, F(4) = 11, F(6) = 41, F(8) = 153,$

and finally,

 $F(10) = 571.$


Good job. I think there is a line of reasoning to derive a finite recurrence, which would be easier to compute for large N.
